# Is there anyway to convert hex string value into long?

Tags: java, type-conversion

I am trying to convert string base address into long value, I tried with different options that do not work.

Option 1: Long.valueoflong(String).longValue(); //not working

Option 2: Long.parseLong(String,16);  //not working

Option 3: BigInteger // not working

```java
public class Strconv {

    private static String x1= "0x40000000";
    private static long x2;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        try {
        x2= Long.valueOf(x1).longValue();
             System.out.println("x2"+x2);
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e) {

           System.out.println("ERRRORRRRRRRRRRRR");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You have to remove the 0x from you hexa address and convert it parseLong(hex, 16)

Answer (score 2):

`Long.parseLong(x2, 16)` would work if you didn't have the leading `0x` in the string.

If you *do* have the leading `0x`, then you need [`Long.decode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#decode(java.lang.String)).